# I can't set the button width inside the table view

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm doing an android application where I have to dynamically put a button inside the table row. The problem is that the button that I create is stretched as in the image below:

[image: screenshot]

I also put some of the application code here below so you can understand better.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_punteggio);
    showAlertDialog_modality(R.layout.dialog_change_modality);
    final TableLayout tableLayout           = findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
    final RelativeLayout relativeLayout           = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    final Button btn_settings = findViewById(R.id.btn_settings);
    Bundle datipassati = getIntent().getExtras();
    String player = datipassati.getString("players");
    giocatore = player.split("%");
    Log.d("TAG", "array: " + giocatore[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < giocatore.length; i++) {
        punti[i] = 0;
        TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);
        final TextView t3v = new TextView(this);
        txPunti[i] = t3v;
        //------------------------- Textview Player
        final TextView t1v = new TextView(this);
        t1v.setText(giocatore[i].toUpperCase());
        t1v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        t1v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        t1v.setTextSize(20);
        t1v.setWidth(400);
        tbrow.addView(t1v);
        //-------------------- BTN MENO
        Button btnMeno = new Button(this);
        btnMeno.setText("-");
        btnMeno.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        btnMeno.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tbrow.addView(btnMeno);
        btnMeno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               removepoint(t3v);
            }
        });
        // --------------------- TEXT VIEW PUNTI
        t3v.setText(punti[i]+"");
        t3v.setTextSize(25);
        t3v.setMaxWidth(150);
        t3v.setPadding(20,0,20,0);
        t3v.setTypeface(t3v.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
        t3v.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        t3v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tbrow.addView(t3v);
        //----------------------------- BTN PIU
        Button btnPiu = new Button(this);
        btnPiu.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Activity_punteggio.this, R.drawable.ic_add_circle_black_24dp));
        btnPiu.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        btnPiu.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tbrow.addView(btnPiu);
        btnPiu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addPoint(t3v, t1v);
            }
        });
        tableLayout.addView(tbrow);
    }
    btn_settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showAlertDialog_modality(R.layout.dialog_change_modality);
        }
    });
}
```

Here's also the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Activity_punteggio">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_player"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Chip-Chop"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp">
</TableLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope you could help me.

Comment: please show your XML file

Comment: the xml file is created dynamically, i will show you anyways...

Comment: check the answer and let me know. Thanks

Comment: let me know bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please check this solution. setImageResource is the method assign
>   image resource. Set background method is recommended for the
>   background of the button.

```
ImageButton btnPiu = new ImageButton(this);

btnPiu.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Activity_punteggio.this, R.drawable.ic_add_circle_black_24dp));

btnPiu.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
btnPiu.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tbrow.addView(btnPiu);
btnPiu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        addPoint(t3v, t1v);
    }
});
tableLayout.addView(tbrow);
```

> I used ImageButton other than Button.
>   setImageDrawable

Comment: It does't work, i have an error inside the setImageResource method.

Here's the problem:

https://prnt.sc/rg859f

Comment: setImageDrawable use this method instead of setImageResource. Hope this will solve your issue. Thanks

Comment: No problem. I am happy to listen. Thanks

Comment: Sorry if i disturb you another time, I tried to get the image bigger, but this happened:
https://prnt.sc/rg8x5c . I want that button to be a little above, in line with the label. Could u help me?

Answer (score 0):

try to edit    `android:layout_height="32dp"` to `android:layout_height="55dp"`

```
  android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
  android:layout_width="55dp"
  android:layout_height="55dp"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"
  android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp" />
```

I hope it will work with you .

Comment: The problem is on the green button, not in the settings one. I want that the green button does not stretch in that way it does.

Answer (score 0):

**THIS is make very complex coding, Make it simpler.Don't create whole row dynamically in FOR loop.**  Instead of that

1. First Create Separate XML for that row.
2. Write Below code and your row append into tablelayout.

   `for (int i = 0; i < giocatore.length; i++) {` 

        `View trView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.xmlID,null);`

        `TextView lblGuestName;`

        `lblGuestName = trView.findViewById(R.id.lbl);`

        `lblGuestName.setText("Guest 1");`

        `tableLayout.addView(trView);`

   `}`

This Way you easily configure any complex row in tablelayout. No need to make it dynamically.
Feel free to reply.